# Регулярное выражение: перед слешем любой символ, кроме другого слеша

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
$text = "/1/2<br />до";

$text = preg_replace('~/.+<br />~U', '<FONT color="red">\\\0</font>', $text);
    echo $text;
```

Вот код.
Скрипт вставляет `<FONT>` к тому, что находится от / до `</br>` включительно.
Вопрос такой. Помогите дополнить регулярку, чтобы программа заменяла шрифт только тогда, когда перед / находится любой другой символ, кроме / 
т.е. если будет " http://1/2<br />до " система это все дело проигнорит.
Я пытался попробовать, но ничего не вышло.

Comment: вот так [^/]?

Comment: Более верно:  

    ~(?<!/)/.+<br />~U

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

```
~(?<!/)/.+<br />~U
```